# Why is Maria Watches Over Us season 3 referred to as an OVA season?

Tags: maria-sama-ga-miteru

Season 1, 2 and 4 of *Maria Watches Over Us* are just normal seasons, but season 3 is described as an OVA season.

Like Maria Watches Over Us season 3, *Full Metal Panic* and *Baka and Test* both had a season set in between 2 seasons, which was an OVA series (Full Metal Panic had *Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu*, Baka and Test had *Baka to Test to Shoukanjuu: Matsuri*). However, in cases of Full Metal Panic and Baka and Test, neither OVA series was counted as a season.

I am wondering: Why was the OVA season of Maria Watches Over Us named the third season instead of making the 4th season the 3rd season, like the case with Baka and Test and Full Metal Panic?